# Why try/exception method is not working on my python?

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

```
import os.path
from os import path
import pandas as pd

class ImportFiles:
    def __init__(self, pathname, file):
        self.pathname = pathname
        self.file = file

    def check(self):
        try:
            os.path.exists(self.pathname+'/'+self.file)
            print(f"'{self.pathname}/{self.file}': this file is valid to use")
        except OSError: 

          
    def import_csv(self):
        df = pd.read_csv(f"{self.pathname}/{self.file}")
        return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    table= ImportFiles("C:/Users/..s", "....csv")
    table.check()
```

This returns

```
'C:/Users/..s/....csv' : this file is valid to use
```

But when I execute the next command

```
table.import_csv()
```

It returns

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/..s/....csv'
```

Not sure why they couldn't find OS error at first?

Edit: Sorry, I simply put print method after except OSError

```
print(f"Operating system raised an error: check if the file {self.file} exsits or the name is correct. Check your path that contains this file.")
```

Comment: Because you `except` statement is empty.

Comment: The code shouldn't run because of empty ```except OSError```. Also, ```except OSError``` will **only** catch ```OSErrors```

Comment: @Sujay `FileNotFoundError` derives from `OSError`, this is not the issue.

Comment: Also you should not join paths by string formatting, you should use `os.path.join()`

Comment: This code *doesn't even compile*

Comment: Sorry the print command must have left out while I was editing the code. Thank you @Prithvi Raj I will replace them with `os.path.join()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) returns True/False. It does not raise an exception. "this file is valid to use" will print regardless of whether the file exists because no exception stopped it.

Comment: That is a good point of course. But please tell OP what to do in this case

Comment: @sujay - I can't. Since OP doesn't show us what the ` except OSError:` case does, I can't implement the `if`.

Comment: Thank you! I know why it is not working now - I will rewrite the code again where it would raise an error :)